# Не выполнять отправку формы

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть форма и скрипт, при нажатии на submit форма отправляется.
Есть переменная `order_i = $('#ordord').val()`
Как сделать если `order_i == 1` форма выполнялась?
Проблема в том что форма выполняется при условии. если ставим if (order_i == 1) { отправка post } else { alert ('привет'); } то если order_i не равен единицы выводится alert, после чего форма отправляется.

```js
function saveorder(event) {
  var order_i = $('#ordord').val()
  event.preventDefault();
  var waiter = document.getElementById('waiter');
  var waiter_value = waiter.options[waiter.selectedIndex].text;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/addorder.php",
    data: {
      waiter: waiter_value
    },
    success: function(html) {
      $("#response3").empty();
      $("#orders").load("orders.php");
      $("#div222").load("ord_table.php");
      $("#response3").append(html);

    }
  });

}
```

```html
<form method="post" onsubmit="saveorder(event)">
  <select id="waiter" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Официант</option>
    <option value="Официант 1">Официант 1</option>
    <option value="Официант 2">Официант 2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @Bald можете отредактировать мой код?

Comment: `addorder.php` вижу вы не используете MVC. Жаль.

Comment: В чем проблема кстати? Какой результат вам нужен?

Comment: @ishidex2 проблема в том что форма выполняется при условии. если ставим if (order_i == 1) { отправка post } else { alert ('привет'); } то если order_i не равен единицы выводится alert, после чего форма отправляется.

Comment: так повести событие?

Comment: @doox911 какое?

Comment: На изменение `select`. А в нём сделайте проверку на значение `value`, и если условие верно отправляйте запрос серверу.

Comment: @Bald не получается.

Comment: что именно не получается, какая ошибка? в приведенном вами примере `order_i` не найден в разметке, может дело в этом?!